# Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:2.4.2-SNAPSHOT:protoc

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, scheduling, hadoop-yarn

Any idea how I can solve this error?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:2.4.2-SNAPSHOT:protoc (compile-protoc) on project hadoop-common: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 'protoc --version' did not return a version -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-common
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing protocolBuffer in Ubuntu using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install protoc
```